# Create 2 independent components DrawerLayout left and right

Tags: java, android

How to create 2 DrawerLayout as in the screenshot. And they should be independent and they can be opened 2 simultaneously
[image]

Comment: I can't even edit your question. Kindly read how to ask a question and use readable english

Comment: have you checked while pressing drawer menu icon if first drawer is opened or not?

Comment: update questions

Comment: You wouldn't be able to _drag_ both drawers open at the same time - in a basic `DrawerLayout`, anyway - but you can open both simultaneously programmatically; e.g., with two toggle buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**two_drawer.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/right_side_header_bg_color"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_right" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**In java file**

```
private NavigationView navigationView_left, navigationView_right;

navigationView_left = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView_left.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
 navigationView_right =(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view_right);
 navigationView_right.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```